# post audio file from document to server

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

hi i am creating a demo application which records audio. i have followed this tutorial

[Link to tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-avfoundation-framework-tutorial/)

```
// Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                               @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                               nil];
    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
```

the recording part is working fine and application is playing the audio file,

Question:
how do i post the recorded file to the server.

Comment: have you implemented webservice ?

Comment: You can upload your outputFilePath to server using ASIHttpRequest or any other framework. refer http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: If problem is "How to upload the file?" why did write all this staff? Please close this ticket and open more specific one.

Comment: well i showed how i recorded the sound now i want to put it server, the audio file is being saved in document and yes i have implemented the web service currently its sending an id, how do i send the complete audio file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use following for example:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session uploadTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:your_url]
                      fromFile:file_url
             completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

             }] resume];
```

Please read more here http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: You are welcome. You can also look at AFNetworking lib if you need more possibilities. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking